# Easy road from DisplayObject to Molehill?

Tags: opengl, flash, actionscript-3, molehill

I have a finished Flash game which is rendered using the built-in display tree, i.e. `Bitmap`s contained in `Sprite`s (and a text here and there, few vector graphics, and one bitmap-filled shape).
For extra performance, I'd like it to use Molehill for rendering, but that's not possible out of the box.

What's the easiest way to make this game use Molehill when available, but fall back to the current method if it's not available?

Comment: Really interesting question

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [ReMx](https://github.com/RetroModular/ReMX/), it's a 2D game dev framework for Molehill, and there is [Away3D](http://away3d.com/comments/away3d-4-0-alpha-release-broomstick) for 3D graphics with Molehill.